# $f$ transforms the unit disc onto itself

Tags: complex-numbers

I have $f(z) = e^{i\alpha} \frac{z- a}{1 - \overline{a}z}$ for $a \in \mathbb{C}$, $|a| < 1$, and $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$.

I've already shown that $f$ maps the unit circle onto itself. Via the following:

$$
(z-a)(\overline{z}-\overline{a})=z\overline{z}-z\overline{a}-a\overline{z}+a\overline{a}=1-z\overline{a}-a\overline{z}+a\overline{a}
$$
$$
(1-\overline{a}z)(1-a\overline{z})=1-a\overline{z}-\overline{a}z+\overline{a}za\overline{z}
$$
These two are equal if you substitute $1$ for $z\overline{z}$ and for a complex number $|z|=1 \iff |z|^2=1 \iff z\overline{z}=1$. Hence $f$ maps the unit circle onto itself. i.e., $|z| = 1 \implies |f(z)| = 1$.

Is showing that $f$ maps the unit disk to itself essentially the same thing? Except, $f$ mapping the unit disk to itself means $|z| \leq 1 \implies |f(z)| \leq 1$. How would it be different?

Comment: That looks like the right idea.

Comment: I do as well, but would the proof for the unit disk be the exact same thing, but with $|z| \leq 1 \iff |z|^2 \leq 1$ and "These two are $\leq 1$ if $z\overline{z} \leq 1$"

Answer (score 0):

A slightly simpler way is to note that if $|z| = 1$, then $\frac{1}{z} = \bar{z}$, so 
$$\left| e^{i\alpha} \frac{z - a}{1 - z \bar{a}} \right| = \left| -\frac{e^{i\alpha}}{z}\frac{z-a}{\overline{z-a}}\right| $$
therefore 
$$\left| e^{i\alpha} \frac{z - a}{1 - z \bar{a}} \right| = 1$$

Then, by the maximum principle, if $z \in \mathbb{D}$, we have $|f(z)| \leq \sup_{|\zeta| = 1} |f(\zeta)| = 1$. The inequality is strict as $f$ is nonconstant. So clearly $f(\mathbb{D}) \subset \mathbb{D}$.

To show that $f$ is in fact an automorphism of $\mathbb{D}$, all you have to do is to find an inverse. But in fact, $f \circ f = \mathrm{id}_{\mathbb{D}}$. So $f$ is a biholomorphism of $\mathbb{D}$.

Such functions are called Möbius transforms. It can be shown that they are the only automorphisms of the disk.

Comment: Ah, this is a bit above my understanding as i'm not sure what automorphisms and biholomorphisms are. Does my comment to Michael hold?

Comment: I think that it would be good to clarify your use of the maximum principle.  Namely, you're using the fact that $|a|<1$ without mention to see that the map is defined on the disk.  Otherwise, the mapping could take the disk to its complement (plus the point at infinity).  Alternately, one could just look at the image of $0$ to see that that case doesn't happen.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't mention it and I should have. The argument is that if $|a|<1$, then the only pole of $f$ is $\frac{1}{\bar{a}}$ which is outside $\overline{\mathbb{D}}$, so $f$ is holomorphic in $\mathbb{D}$ and continuous in $\overline{\mathbb{D}}$ (in fact it's holomorphic on a neighborhood of $\overline{\mathbb{D}}$). The maximum principle applies to $f$ in $\overline{\mathbb{D}}$ to yeld the result.